# Live data not updates after updating record in RecyclerView

Tags: android, fragment, android-livedata

I have an activity which contains fragment and this fragment have Recyclerview. For RecyclerView Adapter, I am using ViewModel with live data. When I add a record to room database recyclerView is updated but when i update or delete a record from recylerView, live data is not updated due to which recyclerVeiw adapter is not updated. To observer live data I used this code in the fragment

```
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
         ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(OrderViewModel::class.jav
         orderViewModel.getBrokerClientOrder(clientUid).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, androidx.lifecycle.Observer {
        orderAdapter!!.refreshOrderAdapter(it)
    })}
```

In Adapter to get an object of ViewModel 
`orderViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(context as AppCompatActivity).get(OrderViewModel::class.java)`
While in activity i used the above mechenism every thing work fine.

Comment: have you tried to notifydatasetchanged() in the recyclerview adapter?

Comment: why aretnt you using either `android.arch.paging.PagedListAdapter` or `android.support.v7.recyclerview.extensions.ListAdapter` ?

Comment: Refer to this answer if it helps in any way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53774111/3358752

Comment: `orderAdapter!!.refreshOrderAdapter(it)` is passing new data to adapter

Comment: I solved it my self. In fragment object of ViewModel created on fragment context while in adapter Object of ViewModel is created on activity context. All I need have to create Object of ViewModel on the same Context.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are observing model changes and passing it to recyclerView, but you need to observe recyclerView changes and pass it to your model.